# Where can I find the DialogFlow CX Agent ID?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Im trying to fill API params: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api.

I couldn't find any reference on how to locate agent ID on its doc: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent.

I couldn't find the ID in Agent's settings in the console.

¿Is it the same as the name of the Agent?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65392455), you can get the Agent ID from the URL when accessing your Dialogflow CX agent in the console. See below:

[image: CX Agent ID]

You can also get the Agent ID via API using the [projects.locations.agents.list](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/list) method.

Note that the Agent ID is not the same as the name of the Agent.

Answer (score 3):

I found the DialogFlow CX API details selecting
["Copy name"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTZxm.png) option of the agent.