# DialogFlow CX Chatbot how to refer to user-id from df-messenger within the DialogFlow Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I am using the following embedded df-messenger javascript in my page:

```
<df-messenger
    df-cx="true"
    location="australia-southeast1"
    chat-title="Cassie"
    agent-id="be11f0b8-f343-408e-98da-749ec04659bd"
    user-id="{{ current_user.name }}"
    language-code="en"
></df-messenger>
```

This is within a flask application, so the current_user.name correctly resolves to 'Mr Smith' when the page is running, but I'm not sure how to access that value within my DialogFlow intents etc. within the DialogFlow CX console. I understand that you are meant to refer to

```
queryParams.payload.userId
```

within your 'detect intent' but I'm not clear on what that means. How can I refer to / display / leverege this value when building my chatbot within the DialogFlow CX console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dialogflow API to perform `detectIntent` as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize).

> user-id - Optional
>
> Can be used to track a user across sessions. You can pass the value to
> Dialogflow through the `queryParams.payload.userId` field in a detect
> intent request, and Dialogflow provides this value to you through the
> `WebhookRequest.payload.userId` field.

Following the documentation, you can send a HTTP request to endpoint [projects.locations.agents.sessions.detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent)  just make sure to use the correct request body. Or use client libraries to do this.

To implement what the documentation says via Python, your code will look like this:

NOTE: I just used a random intent of mine to illustrate what the documentation says. Also you can implement this in other languages like Nodejs, and Java.

```
from google.cloud import dialogflowcx_v3beta1 as dialogflow
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1 import types

import uuid

project_id = "your-project"
location = "us-central1" # my project is located here hence us-central1
session_id = uuid.uuid4()
agent_id = "999999-aaaa-aaaa" # to get your agent_id see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389964/where-can-i-find-the-dialogflow-cx-agent-id
session_path = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/agents/{agent_id}/sessions/{session_id}"

api_endpoint = f"{location}-dialogflow.googleapis.com"
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
client = dialogflow.services.sessions.SessionsClient(client_options=client_options)

event = "custom_event"
event_input = types.EventInput(event=event)
query_input = types.QueryInput(event=event_input,language_code="en-US")
query_params = types.QueryParameters(payload={"userId": "Mr Smith"}) # this is should be similar with queryParams.payload.userId
request = types.DetectIntentRequest(
        session=session_path,
        query_input=query_input,
        query_params=query_params,
        )
response = client.detect_intent(request=request)

print(response)
```

Request as seen in the logs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, but could you clarify something? In my question I was asking about using this parameter within the console, are you saying this is not possible without writing code to interact with the API? At the moment I haven't had to do that. I just embed the chatbot, and use the console to build all my logic.

Comment: @JamesMatson AFAIK the console has no option to use it. Unfortunately you need to use the API for it.